# When does Uri.CheckHostName() return UriHostNameType.Basic instead of UriHostNameType.Dns or UriHostNameType.Unknown?

Tags: c#, mono

The documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.urihostnametype.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.checkhostname.aspx is a bit unclear.

`Uri.CheckHostName(string)` returns `UriHostNameType.Dns` for a valid DNS hostname, and it returns `UriHostNameType.Unknown` when the string contains invalid characters and so on.  Under what conditions does this method ever return `UriHostNameType.Basic`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now the .NET Core is open source we can know for sure.

Just like Mono, it never returns `UriHostNameType.Basic`.

[Link to source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/41e203011152581a6c65bb81ac44ec037140c1bb/src/System.Private.Uri/src/System/Uri.cs#L1216)

Answer (score 4):

It occurred to me that I could just check the Mono source code to answer my question.  Here is the `CheckHostName` method from https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System/Uri.cs:

```
    public static UriHostNameType CheckHostName (string name) 
    {
        if (name == null || name.Length == 0)
            return UriHostNameType.Unknown;

        if (IsIPv4Address (name)) 
            return UriHostNameType.IPv4;

        if (IsDomainAddress (name))
            return UriHostNameType.Dns;             

        IPv6Address addr;
        if (IPv6Address.TryParse (name, out addr))
            return UriHostNameType.IPv6;

        return UriHostNameType.Unknown;
    }
```

It appears that `UriHostNameType.Basic` isn't used at all. Maybe the Microsoft implementation can return this value?

Answer (score 2):

`UriHostNameType.Basic` is used by the `UriBuilder` and `Uri`, when there is a DNS host name where at least 1 of the domain labels begins with a "-" (dash) or an "_" (underscore).  For example, "_caldavs._tcp.google.com" will return `UriHostNameType.Basic`.

However, `Uri.CheckHostName(string)` appears to never return this value.  For the same DNS host name above it returns `UriHostNameType.Unknown`.

Comment: I'm still really curious what 'Basic' means. What does a leading underscore or dash in a host name component have to do with it?

Comment: @Triynko from the documentation at [UriHostNameType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.urihostnametype), you can see that it means, "_The host is set, but the type cannot be determined._".